# What are the steps required to secure a Web API with OAuth?

Tags: web-services, security, oauth, oauth-2.0

And is this the best choice for restricting an HTTP-based API to known clients?

I'm primarily interested in knowing that only certain trusted applications (e.g., native mobile apps) can access the API.

Comment: I think this question could benefit from some elaboration.  What is ment by "clients"?  Software clients?  End users?  And if it's software - do you mean install instances, or just overall 'trusted software packages'?

Comment: @Scott - good suggestion.  I'm looking at mobile apps specifically, but I think 'trusted software packages' sums it up well (or perhaps synonymously, software from registered software developers).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something OAuth 2.0 is designed to solve.  Mobile apps in particular are difficult to identify as "known clients" since they can't keep secrets - their application code is downloaded and could be decompiled by a motivated hacker wanting to write their own client that speaks the same protocol.

The question is somewhat of a duplicate as this one: [OAuth2 security considerations for client_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730590/oauth2-security-considerations-for-client-id)

Comment: Hey @Scott, thanks for the info.  I agree it's not a foolproof plan.  I don't think it's a duplicate though, as I'm legitimately looking for the steps one would take if they had an application they wanted to secure with OAuth.